# Error on Content Entry Submit in EE: Control Panel Giving JSON Responses in the Browser

Tags: ee2, control-panel

I am running into an odd issue when submitting content entry forms in the EE CMS. Whenever I submit a form I see this response in my browser:

[image]

I am not sure what is causing this issue but it seems like an error. Any ideas?

---

EE v2.7.2
Calendar
CartThrob Pro
CT Admin
Freeform
Structure
Wygwam
Matrix
Freebie
And a couple more smaller plug-ins and extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this before as well and it seems to be something that can happen with Media Temple hosting when FastCGI is enabled. It looks like you're using MediaTemple so I'm guessing that's your issue.

There are a couple threads in the EE Forums about this:

- [Control Panel Giving JSON Responses in the Browser on Content Edit /
  Update](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/237463/#1058085)
- [Error When Submitting
  Changes](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/237416/#1058082)

And a warning about ExpressionEngine and Fast CGI in the [Media Temple Knowledge Base](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1890/How+do+I+enable+FastCGI?#gs/req_gs)

The fix is to edit the PHP settings for that domain inside your Media Temple hosting control panel.

Comment: You are correct, the client is using MediaTemple. I will look into you added. Thanks!

Comment: FastCGI is a demon b***. May her ruined corpse be smote upon the mountainside.