# No Head or Footer HTML Loading in CP - v2.8.1

Tags: ee2, control-panel, 2.8

v2.8.1
Build Date: 20140314

Having an issue where the header and footer HTML doesn't load randomly. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. This happens randomly when navigating the CP control panel. It happens more often when submitting or updating a category under Admin > Categories > Create a New Category.

For example, I create a new category and hit the submit button.
The next page returns a response of 200 text/html that looks like this and nothing else.

URL looks this: http://mysite.com/myadmin.php?/cp/admin_content/category_update?S=dbcc62fcecfde00324b7db8e87cef88b

`{"message_success":"Preference Updated"}`

This happens about 80% time. Sometimes it doesn't.

This is hosted on the Media Temple GS. The system folder is above web root. I never remember seeing a question mark after the admin PHP file followed by a slash. My guess is that the CP urls have changed recently?

Anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

**EDIT: This has been fixed. FastCGI enabled on Media Temple's GS was causing this. Switch FastCGI to just CGI. Thanks Alex.**

Comment: Hey Bransin, I'm willing to bet you're running into this error because you're running PHP with FastCGI enabled on Media Temple (gs). See this answer http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/17176/22

Comment: You are absolutely right. I switched FastCGI to the stable release CGI and it now works. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Great! Glad that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely means that one or several of the files in themes folder is not uploaded correctly. Re-upload themes folder and make sure the path and URL for themes folder are correct in EE preferences.